# How to get the center point of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

How to get The center point of the canvas object/rectangle. I use the Konvajs library for my small project. in the konva documentation said that you need to center the point to get good rotation. 
http://konvajs.github.io/docs/animations/Rotation.html

Ex

```
 var yellowRect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 220,
    y: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'yellow',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    offset: {
        x: 50 // how to solve this using formula so it will dynamic,
        y: 25 // how to solve this using formula so it will dynamic
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rotating rectangular objects around their centers**

By default, KonvaJS sets the rotation point of a rectangle at its top-left corner. Therefore to rotate from the center of the rectangle you must push the rotation point to the center of the rectangle.

You can do this by setting the `offsetX=rectangleWidth/2` and `offsetY=rectangleHeight/2`

```
var yellowRectWidth=100;
var yellowRectHeight=50;
var yellowRect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 220,
    y: 75,
    width: yellowRectWidth,
    height: yellowRectHeight,
    fill: 'yellow',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    offset: {
        x: yellowRectWidth/2,
        y: yellowRectHeight/2
    }
});
```

**Rotating circular objects around their centers**

By default, KonvaJS sets the rotation point of circular shapes at their centerpoints. Therefore to rotate from the center of circular shapes you won't have to set any offsets.